# Pandas:iterate through the dataframe and apply changes with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I have to iterate through column=0 and if I find any integer like 2010,2018,2017 etc in my column =0, I have to assign that to all the values in column=0 as year.

PS:-column=0 is an object datatype.

My DF:
    0                 1
    Nan             Banks 
    National Banks  Axis Bank
    Nan             ICICI
    Nan             PNB
    2010            KYB
    Nan             Indus Ind
    Nan             Karur

My desired output:
    0                 1
        2010             Banks 
        2010           Axis Bank
        2010             ICICI
        2010            PNB
        2010            KYB
        2010            Indus Ind
        2010            Karur

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question accordingly :)

Comment: What is expected output if `Nan` after `National Banks` is `2015` ?

Comment: Firstly, thank you jezrael for your time...i just want to replace all(including nan,national banks) the values in column=0 with the integer value i get (ex.2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and then convert all numbers outside `range` to missing values to `NaN`s by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with mask by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce')
df[0] = s.where(s.isin(range(2010, 2020)))
print (df)
        0          1
0     NaN      Banks
1     NaN  Axis Bank
2     NaN      ICICI
3     NaN        PNB
4  2010.0        KYB
5     NaN  Indus Ind
6     NaN      Karur
```

Comment: The above answer is partially useful....i want to replace the column=0 values with whatever integer value i get(ex.2010,2011etc)...should we use iteritems()?

Comment: @HarshaRagyari - in column is always only one unique year? If yes, then use `df[0] = s.where(s.isin(range(2010, 2020))).dropna().iat[0]`

Comment: @HarshaRagyari - If possible multiple values then `df[0] = s.where(s.isin(range(2010, 2020))).ffill().bfill()` should help.

Comment: Ty, i am able to get my desired output now..               t=pd.to_numeric(df[0],errors='coerce')
t

df[0]=t.where(t.isin(range(2005,2020))).dropna().values[0]
df[0]